# validatorjs is passing all test cases when using wildcard, even when test should fail

Tags: node.js, validation, validator.js

I have an array of order objects, and I'm trying to validate properties on each object. [my runkit code example here](https://runkit.com/yzpaul/validatorjs-wildcard-issues). Can someone tell me why this is passing tests, when it should fail them, and how to fix it?

object body is an array of objects:

```
  let body={order:[
  {CompanyId:12},
  {CompanyId:00}]}
```

validation rule:

```
const orderValidationRule = {
  "order.*.CompanyId": "required|digits_between:4,6", //4 to 6 digits long
  "order.*.Location": "required:size:2", 
  "order.*.CustomerId": "required:min:0"}
```

calling a validation method to check the objects:

```
const validator = (body, rules, customMessages, callback) => {
  const validation = new Validator(body, rules, customMessages);
  validation.passes(() => callback(null, true));
  validation.fails(() => callback(validation.errors, false));
};

  validator(body.order, orderValidationRule, {}, (err, status) => {
  if (!status) {
    throw `validation failed: ${JSON.stringify(err)}`;
  }
  else{
    console.log(`validation success: ${status} ${JSON.stringify(body.order)}`)
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was formatting the order validation rules wrong. I needed:

```
"order.*.CompanyId": "between:1000,9999999|numeric"
"order.*.Location": "required|size:2"
"order.*.CustomerId": "required|min:0|numeric"
```